# Spring - how to load properties prior to context loader getting called

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I would like to read the properties from my properties files in my custom contextLoadListener. However my listener class gets executed prior to spring loading the properties file. How do I get my 'rdbaccess.properties' loaded prior to the execution of my CustomContextLoaderListener class? Below is my relevant parts of the configuration.

In web.xml

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
<listener>

    <listener-class>
        com.my.package.setup.CustomContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>

</listener>
```

In spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:rdbaccess.properties" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The ContextLoader(Listener) is the instance that initializes your Spring context. This has to be the very first thing happening in the lifecycle of your (Spring) application, at all. It's not possible that your properties get loaded before the context has initialized. You can't decorate your living room before you've built the house :)

However, regarding the name of your properties, you probably need to inject the database credentials into your beans. This issue can be resolved with another approach, which is a lot cleaner in my opinion, especially for applications that run in multiple environments.

Instead of keeping/putting the credentials in your classpath, you should configure properties that change for each environment (local, development, integration, production ...) right there. For example, if you run a Tomcat, then put a properties file into the `conf` directory containing your database credentials. You can access that file in your custom `ContextLoaderListener` and provide the properties to your beans through a class with a static properties map, for instance.

Comment: But you need to adopt which building code first before you buiild your house. This is what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a custom context initializer to load your properties file, like so:

https://gist.github.com/rponte/3989915